# Leer un fichero Excel .csv (C++)

Tags: c++, csv

Estoy intentando leer datos de un fichero Excel guardado en formato csv, mi fichero excel tiene seis filas y 49 columnas, como podeis ver en la foto:

[image]

Quiero leer datos de ese fichero, estoy haciendo este código:

```
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("datacsvformatdelimitadoporcomas.csv");
string nombre2="factura";
string b= ".xml";
string suma= nombre2+ b;
ofstream fout(suma.c_str());
vector<string> cabeceras;

string campo;
string line;
while(getline(inFile, line)){//coges linea por linea
    istringstream s(line);
    string field;
    while (getline(line,campo,';')) {
        cabeceras.push_back(campo);
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<cabeceras.size();i++){
    cout<<cabeceras[i]<<endl;
}
```

Sin embargo, me da errores al compilar:

El error es este:

```
no matching function for call to 'getline(std::string&, std::string&, char)'
```

Refiriendose a esta primera linea:

```
while (getline(line,campo,';'))
```

Le he quitado el ; pero de igual forma me sigue saliendo el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) espera recibir un flujo de datos de entrada, tú le estás pasando una cadena de caracteres, de ahí el error:

> ```
> no matching function for call to 'getline(std::string&, std::string&, char)'
> ```

Que básicamente te está diciendo que no hay ninguna versión de `getline` que acepte dos `std::string` como primer y segundo parámetro seguido de un `char` como tercer parámetro. Seguramente querías escribir esto:

```
istringstream s(line);
string field;
while (getline(s, field, ';'))
```